# Convert R RasterStack class into a NetCDF CF-1.6 convention

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I have a R RasterStack class in my R-Project and I would like to make a **NetCDF file CF-1.6 compliant** using the RasterStack class. How can I do it?

The RasterStack has the following properties

`class      : RasterStack  dimensions : 97, 107, 10379, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers) resolution : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y) extent     : -58.45, -53.1, -34.95, -30.1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0  names      : X2020.06.21, X2020.06.26, X2020.07.01, X2020.07.06, X2020.07.11,  X2020.07.16  min values :    15.17224,    16.62855,    17.57079,    25.34024,    37.90452,    35.48506  max values :    56.56909,    63.15136,    64.47987,    64.54590,    83.37997,    87.15372  time        : 2020-06-21, 2020-06-26, 2020-07-01, 2020-07-06, 2020-07-11, 2020-07-16`

What I been trying to do is to create a netcdf file using the WriteRaster function. However, when I open the netcdf the Convention format is CF-1.4.

`myRaster <- writeRaster(raster.file,"prctl3_26072020.nc",format="CDF", overwrite=TRUE,varname="percentile")`

I would like to obtain a NetCDF File CF 1.6 since I want to import that data into another platform which require NetCDF CF 1.6 in order to work. There is a [Compliance Checker](https://pumatest.nerc.ac.uk/cgi-bin/cf-checker.pl) which allows to compare your netcdf file againts different CF versions. When I upload my created [Netcdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oiiAfGoKqU5SFj8jC6U3t9h0nL0LR58T/view?usp=sharing) I got a warning message saying that my CF is 1.4

How can I change the Convention from CF-1.4 to CF-1.6 in the Global Attributes?

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Can you please show evidence of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question with the function that I have tried so far...

Comment: Have you checked if the file is cf 1.6 compliant? Or 1.4 compliant? If it is 1.6 compliant just change the file attributes

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote that function I attempted to be CF 1.4 compliant --- whether this is actually correct is another matter; but I have not heard otherwise. It is likely that most 1.4 compliant files are also 1.6 compliant, as Robert Wilson points out.

However, if this is not the case for the files created with `raster::writeRaster`, can you point out what would need to be changed? Then we might be able to help you with that (and I could update the code).

Comment: Thank you Robert Hijmans and Robert Wilson. I´ll edit my edit question (again) in order to explain better my question.

Comment: I am not sure your revision helps. You need to check if the file is 1.6 compliant. If it is not, simply changing an attribute will not make it 1.6 compliant.

Comment: The nc file created by the writeRaster funcion is definitely 1.4 compliant. When I open the file in the global properties displays Conventions: CF-1.4.